# Where to find gdb for an arm target running on linux 2.6.21.5-cfs-v19

Tags: linux, gdb, arm

I have a ARM11 based hardware board which runs a Linux kernel ver. 2.6.21.5-cfs-v19. I have my application running on this ARM-LINUX board. To do source level debugging, of my application I used to use gdb from command prompt of the linux board, that was with some earlier version of the board linux version.

With this version 2.6.21.5-cfs-v19, I dont have a related version of gdb for the board. I tried to look around to get gdb for this version of linux and arm port of it, but without much success. Can anyone point me where I can get either an independant executable for gdb for above mentioned os and board configuration or source for the same, which I may try compiling for that target.

-AD.

Comment: Wanna fix up the title a bit? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime ago I published an [article](http://www.linux.com/feature/121735) about cross-target debugging with GDB and GDBServer. The target processor there is PPC7450, but it's rather detailed, so maybe you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck using [OpenEmbedded](http://wiki.openembedded.net/index.php/Main_Page). If there's no precompiled version you can use right away, setting up an OE-cross compile environment is not that hard.

Another option could be to install gdb-server on the board, like described in [this blogpost](http://dominion.thruhere.net/koen/cms/using-gdbserver).